# What is the closest anyone got to a proper description of a Galilean universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, galilean-relativity

So assuming Einsteinian relativity is a bust, did any physicist thought through properly how a Galilean/Newtonian universe would work? Of course there are infinite ways of how it could, but one is already more than I have.

I search about this topic every once in a while, but Google never seems to turn up good results, so I have to assume I use the wrong words or there are no such studies.

Comment: That's rather a bold thing to assume.

Comment: Tip: Try search for _Newtonian cosmology._

Comment: Is there a particular aspect of the universe that you're interested in, e.g. the large-scale time evolution?

Comment: maybe this  will inform you enough https://web.mit.edu/8.286/www/lecn18/ln03-euf18.pdf

Comment: You wouldn’t just need Galilean cosmology. You’d also need Galilean electrodynamics, Galilean quantum field theory, etc.